# Tricky Triangle Design implementation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

I am working on a website at the moment and have run into a problem with a triangle pattern.

The designer mocked the site up with triangular tiles and patterns :

[image: triangle pattern]

Please note that I had to remove most of the content to post it here, but there is content on top of the triangular pattern.

I have done some research on how to implement the triangles in HTML,CSS and possibly JS(?) and came up with three possible options:

- background-image
- clipping divs and positioning them
- using svg and positioning this

The problem with a background-image is that some of these tiles will later change on click and show things etc. So they really shouldn't be on a picture

I have started clipping and positioning divs, but this is just taking forever and I am starting to feel like this cannot be the best solution. Loads of fiddling and I think I will later have problems with inconsistencies

I don't have much experience working with svg, but I would have to draw them all one by one and position them as well (right? this is an assumption). Doesn't seem like the best practice approach.

Does anyone have any input on how I could solve this or do I just have to follow through with one of the solutions named above, as there is no quicker way.

I would really appreciate any ideas.
Thanks Anton

Comment: Can you share the code you have now please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to go with the SVG route then the code to create the triangles can be relatively small. Store the colors in an array of arrays. Store the horizontal and vertical distance between triangles in two variables (e.g. dx and dy). Then loop through the colors array to draw the individual triangles.

JavaScript code...

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function drawTriangles() {
  var svg = document.getElementById("mySvg");
  var colors = [
    ["#0000FF", "#0044FF", "#0088FF", "#00CCFF"],
    ["#4400FF", "#4444FF", "#4488FF", "#44CCFF"],
    ["#8800FF", "#8844FF", "#8888FF", "#88CCFF"],
    ["#CC00FF", "#CC44FF", "#CC88FF", "#CCCCFF"],
  ];
  var n = colors.length;
  var m = colors[0].length;
  var dx = 100;
  var dy = 75;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      var polygon = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "polygon");
      var point0 = svg.createSVGPoint();
      var point1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
      var point2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
      if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
        point0.x = j * dx;
        point0.y = i * dy;
        point1.x = (j + 1) * dx;
        point1.y = (i + 1) * dy;
        point2.x = (j + 1) * dx;
        point2.y = (i - 1) * dy;
      } else {
        point0.x = (j + 1) * dx;
        point0.y = i * dy;
        point1.x = j * dx;
        point1.y = (i - 1) * dy;
        point2.x = j * dx;
        point2.y = (i + 1) * dy;
      }
      polygon.setAttribute("fill", colors[i][j]);
      polygon.points.appendItem(point0);
      polygon.points.appendItem(point1);
      polygon.points.appendItem(point2);
      svg.appendChild(polygon);
    }
  }
}
drawTriangles();
```

```html
<svg id="mySvg" width="400" height="225"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome! using this now

Answer (score 0):

If css shapes are an option, i would recommend to use them.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

However you chose to create the boundaries of your containers, if you embed the svg directly into the html, you can access all the elements the same way you access html elements, and with them you can get their vertices. This way you could use that information to create the shapes.

The downside of that approach is that it is highly depending on javascript, if it is disabled or fails, the complete layout will fail, too. But you can react on layout changes at runtime.

To overcome this you might be able to process the svg on the server, but there you are missing out the final dimensions, what might not be problem if you use percentage values to position your content containers, but a huzzle to code.

All in all, if got this right, creating such a layout where content is arranged in triangles will need a lot of code in each case.

If the page will stay small and not much content be assigned, than doing everything by hand might be faster.